What does Lai-Ching Te want to talk to China about?
This article includes this paragraph (in the context of a Chinese invasion of Taiwan):

President Lai, whom China calls a "separatist," has repeatedly offered talks with Beijing but has been rebuffed. He says only Taiwan’s people can decide their future.

What does President Lai want to talk to Beijing about? Superficially it doesn't seem like there's much to discuss - either Taiwan is independent, or it is not. The positions are mutually incompatible, making any talks futile.

I don't think the situation is nearly as black-and-white as you portray it. Consider the following pairs: Catalonia - Spain, Quebec - Canada, Hong Kong - China, Northern Ireland - UK, Monaco - France, Greenland - Denmark. All of these are at different points inbetween fully independent and fully dependent.

@quarague Are you suggesting that Taiwan is willing to give up some level of political control to China? If so, do you have a source?

I don't know, I just think your conclusion 'any talks are futile' is going to way to far. I mean they could even just formalize the status quo.

@quarague how would formalizing the status quo work? It sounds like China acknowledging Taiwanese de facto independence.

There's a lot to be discussed: travel arrangements, economic cooperation, trade, border disputes, consular services, family reunification, maybe demilitarisation in some areas, as well as some degree of recognition. The USSR and USA held frequent talks during the Cold War, for instance, and North and South Korea have held meetings at times despite being technically still at war.

@StuartF if you have a source that the proposed talks are not about the political status of Taiwan, I'd suggest writing that as an answer.

Not much of an agenda has been made public.

"I will not rule out dialogue with China on the principles of mutual respect, mutual benefits, and dignity," Lai said at the Copenhagen Democracy Summit in a pre-recorded video, adding that such dialogue should be conducted "with no preconditions."
[...]
Beijing has insisted on Taipei accepting the "1992 consensus," under which both sides of the Taiwan Strait belong to one China, as a prerequisite for dialogue.

And of course, trolling the PRC about land lost to Russia probably doesn't help.

OTOH China did receive in April former president Ma Ying-jeou, whose party (KMT) is now in opposition, but there's more than that, he himself has been sidelined inside the party. However, other KMT leaders also visited frequently:

China, though, thinks there is still a benefit to embracing people like Mr Ma. Officials in Beijing stress the importance of supporting Taiwan’s “patriotic unification forces”. China’s Taiwan Affairs Office (TAO) receives a steady stream of delegations made up of Taiwanese religious leaders, businessmen and students. Andrew Hsia, the KMT’s vice-chairman, has visited China at least seven times since 2022. Chinese leaders seem to believe that by dividing the island now they may one day win it over. Even though Mr Lai was victorious, his Democratic Progressive Party (DPP) lost its majority in parliament and most Taiwanese back more cross-strait talking.
There is also a domestic component to China’s strategy. “Beijing is telling its own people that it has not lost control over the Taiwan issue and that there is still time to achieve unification,” says Amanda Hsiao of Crisis Group, a think-tank. The Ma-Xi meeting, front-page news in China, aimed to make that point.

So China's refusal to talk isn't because there's nothing to talk about, but because they calculate/hope that [like in many democracies] being in power for a while will erode DDP's vote share eventually, and their favorite interlocutors will be back in Taipei. I.e. China's biding its time on this (too).

As for topics for discussion, here's an example:  China is willing [e.g.] to discuss more tourism, just not with the DDP.
